# VB.Net ProcessStartInfo not working in Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, command

I want to stop a windows service in a different service.
When I run the below code in a desktop app, it works correctly but same code doesn't work in a Windows Service app.

Is somebody has any idea?

PS: I tried to use SC stop instead of net stop but the result is exactly the same.

```
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        pi.Arguments = " " + "/K" + " " + "net stop MyService"
        pi.CreateNoWindow = True
        pi.UseShellExecute = True
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        pi.Verb = "runas"

        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? are you getting an exception, error code, or is the command being spawned, but not doing what you expect? What credentials is the service running as? Is the service trying to stop itself, or a different service?

Comment: @RowlandShaw    When I debug it I see that command window doesn't open. There is no error, no exception, and no result.  the service is trying to stop a different service, not itself. The exact code is running properly in a Windows desktop application.

Comment: Is the service that this is running from set to be allowed to interact with the desktop, does process monitor (or similar) show that the process was spawned?

Comment: Services usually run in their own user account unless you've set it to interact with the user's desktop. If you haven't changed that setting you will not see the CMD window open.